# Parallel index-only scan with two sub-queries is slow

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, subquery, postgresql-13

I'm trying to analyze a slow query that uses parallel index-only scan of two filters (using sub-queries). Specifically I'm the number of 'open_questions' that returned by either subplan1 OR subplan2.
The query itself is generated by Django ORM, so I can definitely see that there are places I can optimize it (doing the sub-sub query of `U0."final_answer" IN ('1st Option')` and `U0."final_answer" IN NULL`.

However, running `explain (analyze, buffers)` showed me that the culprit of the slowness is the Parallel Index Only Scan using primary key of open_question. It was over-estimated the returned ids by 19M+ records (the table size of `open_question` is roughly 19.5M rows)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "__count"
FROM
    "open_question"
WHERE
    (
        "open_question"."id" IN (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT U0."id"
            FROM
                "open_question" U0
                INNER JOIN "book" U1 ON (U0."book_id" = U1."id")
                INNER JOIN "picture" U3 ON (U0."picture_id" = U3."id")
            WHERE
                (
                    NOT (
                        U0."final_answer" IN (
                            'DELETED',
                            'DELETED_NOT_ANSWERED',
                            'NO_ONE_ANSWER'
                        )
                        AND U0."final_answer" IS NOT NULL
                    )
                    AND U1."project_id" = '107e827e-346a-4178-bb53-7cbd2ff0d66c'::uuid
                    AND U3."picture_group_id" IN ('ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid)
                    AND U3."color_schema_id" IN ('2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid)
                    AND U0."book_id" IN (
                        'ef4ad3c8-8ff5-411b-8577-202212202103'::uuid,
                        '671d56b3-41f1-450b-afbf-202212191825'::uuid,
                        'c986ce5e-36ad-44d0-a2ab-202212132131'::uuid,
                        ... 40 more records
                    )
                    AND (U0."final_answer" IN ('1st Option') 
                )
        )
        OR "open_question"."id" IN (
            SELECT
                V0."open_question_id"
            FROM
                "scoped_question" V0
            WHERE
                (
                    V0."date_submitted" IS NULL
                    AND V0."date_answered" IS NULL
                    AND V0."open_question_id" IN (
                        SELECT
                            DISTINCT U0."id"
                        FROM
                            "open_question" U0
                            INNER JOIN "book" U1 ON (U0."book_id" = U1."id")
                            INNER JOIN "picture" U3 ON (U0."picture_id" = U3."id")
                        WHERE
                            (
                                NOT (
                                    U0."final_answer" IN (
                                        'DELETED',
                                        'DELETED_NOT_ANSWERED',
                                        'NO_ONE_ANSWER'
                                    )
                                    AND U0."final_answer" IS NOT NULL
                                )
                                AND U1."project_id" = '107e827e-346a-4178-bb53-7cbd2ff0d66c'::uuid
                                AND U3."picture_group_id" IN ('ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid)
                                AND U3."color_schema_id" IN ('2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid)
                                AND U0."book_id" IN (
                                    'ef4ad3c8-8ff5-411b-8577-202212202103'::uuid,
                                    '671d56b3-41f1-450b-afbf-202212191825'::uuid,
                                    'c986ce5e-36ad-44d0-a2ab-202212132131'::uuid,
                                    ... 40 more records as above

                                )
                                AND U0."final_answer" IS NULL
                            )
                    )
                    AND V0."type" IN ('REVALIDATE_ANSWER')
                )
        )
    );
```

Running each of the sub-plans individually is very fast, and eventually the result of all this long query is 2 (only 2 open_questions).

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=479208.85..479208.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10159.397..10164.554 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=18316732 read=77554
   I/O Timings: read=150757.132
   ->  Gather  (cost=479208.63..479208.84 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=10159.041..10164.548 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=18316732 read=77554
         I/O Timings: read=150757.132
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=478208.63..478208.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=10154.771..10154.782 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=18316732 read=77554
               I/O Timings: read=150757.132
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using open_question_pkey on open_question  (cost=155.73..463070.55 rows=6055232 width=0) (actual time=5538.715..10154.776 rows=1 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 6471867
                     Heap Fetches: 4463629
                     Buffers: shared hit=18316732 read=77554
                     I/O Timings: read=150757.132
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Unique  (cost=74.48..74.49 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=330.591..330.599 rows=2 loops=3)
                             Buffers: shared hit=4993 read=595
                             I/O Timings: read=568.918
                             ->  Sort  (cost=74.48..74.49 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=330.590..330.595 rows=2 loops=3)
                                   Sort Key: u0.id
                                   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                   Buffers: shared hit=4993 read=595
                                   I/O Timings: read=568.918
                                   Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                   Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.74..74.47 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=207.845..329.926 rows=2 loops=3)
                                         Buffers: shared hit=4976 read=595
                                         I/O Timings: read=565.144
                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.45..71.40 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=207.823..329.890 rows=2 loops=3)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=4956 read=595
                                               I/O Timings: read=565.144
                                               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on picture u3  (cost=33.89..35.37 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=2.851..3.235 rows=118 loops=3)
                                                     Recheck Cond: ((picture_group_id = 'ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid) AND (color_schema_id = '2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid))
                                                     Heap Blocks: exact=118
                                                     Buffers: shared hit=411 read=7
                                                     I/O Timings: read=6.323
                                                     ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=33.89..33.89 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.830..2.831 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                           Buffers: shared hit=57 read=7
                                                           I/O Timings: read=6.323
                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on picture_picture_group_id_ea80b794  (cost=0.00..12.02 rows=549 width=0) (actual time=2.221..2.221 rows=792 loops=3)
                                                                 Index Cond: (picture_group_id = 'ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid)
                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=28 read=7
                                                                 I/O Timings: read=6.323
                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on color_schema_id_c798104e  (cost=0.00..21.62 rows=2042 width=0) (actual time=0.567..0.568 rows=4973 loops=3)
                                                                 Index Cond: (color_schema_id = '2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid)
                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=29
                                               ->  Index Scan using open_question_id_ff531421 on open_question u0  (cost=0.56..36.02 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=2.736..2.765 rows=0 loops=354)
                                                     Index Cond: (picture_id = u3.id)
                                                     Filter: ((final_answer = '1st Option'::text) AND ((final_answer <> ALL ('{DELETED,DELETED_NOT_ANSWERED,NO_ONE_ANSWER}'::text[])) OR (final_answer IS NULL)) AND (book_id = ANY ('{ef4ad3c8-8ff5-411b-8577-202212202103,671d56b3-41f1-450b-afbf-202212191825,c986ce5e-36ad-44d0-a2ab-202212132131, ...}'::uuid[])))
                                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 27
                                                     Buffers: shared hit=4545 read=588
                                                     I/O Timings: read=558.821
                                         ->  Index Scan using book_pkey on book u1  (cost=0.29..3.06 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=6)
                                               Index Cond: (id = u0.book_id)
                                               Filter: (project_id = '107e827e-346a-4178-bb53-7cbd2ff0d66c'::uuid)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=20
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=74.74..80.67 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6.960..6.965 rows=0 loops=3)
                             Buffers: shared hit=4624
                             ->  Unique  (cost=74.32..74.33 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6.959..6.964 rows=0 loops=3)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=4624
                                   ->  Sort  (cost=74.32..74.33 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6.959..6.963 rows=0 loops=3)
                                         Sort Key: u0_1.id
                                         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                         Buffers: shared hit=4624
                                         Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                         Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.74..74.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6.950..6.953 rows=0 loops=3)
                                               Buffers: shared hit=4624
                                               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.45..71.34 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6.949..6.952 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                     Buffers: shared hit=4624
                                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on picture u3_1  (cost=33.89..35.37 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.686..0.927 rows=118 loops=3)
                                                           Recheck Cond: ((picture_group_id = 'ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid) AND (color_schema_id = '2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid))
                                                           Heap Blocks: exact=118
                                                           Buffers: shared hit=414
                                                           ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=33.89..33.89 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.667..0.668 rows=0 loops=3)
                                                                 Buffers: shared hit=60
                                                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on picture_picture_group_id_ea80b794  (cost=0.00..12.02 rows=549 width=0) (actual time=0.088..0.089 rows=792 loops=3)
                                                                       Index Cond: (picture_group_id = 'ff3d7383-f086-499d-b59c-09d49733e327'::uuid)
                                                                       Buffers: shared hit=33
                                                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on color_schema_id_c798104e  (cost=0.00..21.62 rows=2042 width=0) (actual time=0.538..0.539 rows=4973 loops=3)
                                                                       Index Cond: (color_schema_id = '2ee66308-1b4b-4473-b2b8-717974ccbfdf'::uuid)
                                                                       Buffers: shared hit=27
                                                     ->  Index Scan using open_question_id_ff531421 on open_question u0_1  (cost=0.56..35.97 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=0 loops=354)
                                                           Index Cond: (picture_id = u3_1.id)
                                                           Filter: ((final_answer IS NULL) AND ((final_answer <> ALL ('{DELETED,DELETED_NOT_ANSWERED,NO_ONE_ANSWER}'::text[])) OR (final_answer IS NULL)) AND (book_id = ANY ('{ef4ad3c8-8ff5-411b-8577-202212202103,671d56b3-41f1-450b-afbf-202212191825,c986ce5e-36ad-44d0-a2ab-202212132131, ...}'::uuid[])))
                                                           Rows Removed by Filter: 27
                                                           Buffers: shared hit=4210
                                               ->  Index Scan using book_pkey on book u1_1  (cost=0.29..2.96 rows=1 width=16) (never executed)
                                                     Index Cond: (id = u0_1.book_id)
                                                     Filter: (project_id = '107e827e-346a-4178-bb53-7cbd2ff0d66c'::uuid)
                             ->  Index Scan using single_scoped_question_per_eta on scoped_question v0  (cost=0.42..3.37 rows=1 width=16) (never executed)
                                   Index Cond: (open_question_id = u0_1.id)
                                   Filter: ((date_submitted IS NULL) AND (type = 'RECALLED_ANSWER'::text))
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1491
 Planning Time: 4.680 ms
 Execution Time: 10165.867 ms
(101 rows)
```

What bothers me specifically is this part (node):

```
Parallel Index Only Scan using open_question_pkey on open_question  (cost=155.73..463070.55 rows=6055232 width=0) (actual time=5538.715..10154.776 rows=1 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 6471867
                     Heap Fetches: 4463629
                     Buffers: shared hit=18316732 read=77554
                     I/O Timings: read=150757.132
```

Why does Postgres so way off here? If I reduce the query to just count by specific open questions (as returned from the 2 subqueries), the result is very fast and uses the same index.
I also suspect that since Postgres over estimate the number of returned rows from the filter (6471867 times 3 due to parallelism) it actually does some kind of sequence scan on 19M records.

Would like to get better explanation on what's going inside Postgres

Comment: Aer you sure this plan is correct?  I don't understand how it is possible to have 150 seconds of IO reads taken place in 10 seconds of execution time.  That would take 5 times more parallel work than you show having.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (without looking into the source code) PostgreSQL only knows of one way to execute a query filter like `WHERE col1 in (select...) or col2 in (select...)`, so it doesn't bother trying to come up with very good row estimates.  When only one branch or the other is there, it will rewrite the query into a different form in which it can both get better estimates and better execution. But with the OR in place, it can't do that.

I can't explain why it isn't using a seq scan, in my hands it does use one.  (But it won't use parallel workers, no matter what I do)

Note that the actual execution of this should be much better if you vacuum the table so that most of those "heap fetches" disappear.